$\|\phi^{(n)}(I)\|=\|\phi(1)\|$
I want to prove $\|\phi^{(n)}(I)\|=\|\phi(1)\|$ where $\phi^{(n)}(I)=\operatorname{diag}(\phi(1),...\phi(1))$ (matrix) and $\phi$ is a completely positive map between $C^*$-algebras.
For $A:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is clear, because for $A=\operatorname{diag}(a,...,a)$ we have
$$
\|Ax\|^2=a^2(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)=a^2\|x\|^2
$$
but for a general context I'm lost...

If it's clear for $A:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$, there's no real difference with the case you want to make. You have
$$
\|\phi^{(n)}(I)\tilde\xi\|^2=\left\|\begin{bmatrix} \phi(1)\xi_1\\ \vdots \\ \phi(1)\xi_n\end{bmatrix}\right\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n \|\phi(1)\xi_j\|^2\leq\|\phi(1)\|^2\sum_j\|\xi_j\|^2=\|\phi(1)\|^2\,\|\tilde\xi\|^2.
$$
Also, given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$ there exists $\xi$ with $\|\xi\|=1$ and $\|\phi(1)\xi\|>\|\phi\|-\e$. Then
$$
\left\|\phi^{(n)}(I)\begin{bmatrix} \xi\\0 \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\|\phi(1)\xi\|>\|\phi\|-\e. 
$$
Thus $\|\phi^{(n)}(1)\|=\|\phi(1)\|$.
The proof is the exact proof of the more general case of the norm of a block diagonal operator  (the norm is the sup of the norms of the diagonal blocks).
